# How prove this $n$ smaller cubes ( length is $1,2,3,\cdots,n$) can't Mosaic a big cube

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

> Show that: for any postive  integer $n(n\ge 2)$, there are $n$  cubes ( length is  $1,2,3,\cdots,n$) can't Mosaic a big cube

This is  answer it is clear when $n=2,3$.
.But I can't prove for general $n$

This Problem background is from by IMC 2000 second day problem 1,can see:http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2000/prob_sol2.pdf

My idea : maybe my problem is $=$ follow equation?:for any $n\ge 2$,
$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3=\left(1+2+\cdots+n\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=k^3$$

maybe this is old problem? because I found this simaler problem [problem](http://www.squaring.net/sq/ss/ss.html).if  you someone take someone usefull  information.

Thank you

Comment: Do you require the smaller cubes to be distinct sizes?

Comment: @Henry: This is probably implied by “length is $1, 2, 3, …, n$.”

Comment: @k.stm: if they are distinct then it is physically impossible for the reason marty cohen gives. But the linked IMC question does not prohibit cubes of the same size.  And anyway this question seems to be more about number theory: is there a solution greater than $1$ to $\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=k^3$

Comment: The number theory question depends on finding more solutions to $2x^3-y^3=\pm1$: if there is one (which I doubt) then $k=x^2y^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have *any* combination
of distinct integer-sided cubes
that will exactly fill
a larger cube.

This was explained in
Martin Gardner's column on
"Squaring the Square".
I will try to recreate the argument there.

The basic idea is to
look at a side of the cube.
Consider the smallest cube on that side.
It must be surrounded by larger cubes.
Now look at what is
on top of that smallest cube.
There can only be smaller cubes.
Now look at the smallest cube there.
This is a start of
an infinite regression,
which must eventually stop
because the sides of the cubes
are all integers.

Note:
It is amazing to me
how many results depend on
the difference between consecutive integers
being bounded below
(i.e., by one).